# Calligraphy library by chrisjenx is not working

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font, calligraphy

I did what his documentation has instructed upon setting up the default font:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupDefaultFont();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupToolbarAndNavigationDrawer();
  }

  public void setupDefaultFont() {
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                        .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf")
                        .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                        .build()
        );
  }
```

I also placed the fonts in `assets/fonts`, but to no avail.
Roboto still shows up as default font and not Open Sans. I tried applying it manually one by one to each `TextView`, but still it doesn't work.

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

More info: (In case it is useful)
My miniSdkVersion is 15 and targetSdkVersion is 22.
These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
}
```

And this is the custom theme that I am using.

```
<resources>
    <style name="myIIT_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/tertiary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/selected_drawer</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the configuration to take effect, you should set up the default font in the onCreate() method of your custom **application** class, instead of in the activity.

Also, the instructions at https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy say to inject into the context, by overriding a method in the **activity** as follows:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway! Just found out about it before you answered. Was supposed to answer it on my own here. Thanks though.

Comment: So we need to override attachBaseContext() in every Activity?

Comment: Yes. Or create a common super class, and inherit every Activity from it.

Comment: its not working anymore in appcompatViews in android API 26 !

Answer (score 4):

Along with @Theo's answer, make sure you register your custom Application in the Manifest

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApplication" <----------- HERE
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the Readme file in github, 
This version of Calligraphy has reached its end-of-life and is no longer maintained. Please migrate to [Calligraphy 3](https://github.com/InflationX/Calligraphy)!

Answer (score 0):

1.Please update your code with below the code:

```
 ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                        new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/century_gothic.ttf")
                                .setFontAttrId(io.github.inflationx.calligraphy3.R.attr.fontPath)
                                .build()))
                .build());
```

2. Put below the code in Class:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
       super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
   }
   ```